# What does the phrase "build into fighting powerhouses " mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

> This fighting game allows you to collect some of the biggest names in action movies and build them into fighting powerhouses.

Does the phrase mean "include in the fighters' teams"?

Answer (score 3):

It means "train them to be very strong fighters".

Answer (score 1):

My first reading was that you make each person into a powerhouse as defined in (2) below.

However there is an ambiguity: it could mean you amalgamate a combination of the heroes into a fighting force.

I doesn't mean 'to incorporate a single person into an existing team.'

> Definition of powerhouse
>
> ...
>
> 2 : one having great power: such as
>
> a : one having great drive, energy, or ability 'a powerhouse rock
>   band'
>
> b : an athletic team characterized by strong aggressive play
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/powerhouse